# Fluent NHibernate - recursive maps

Tags: nhibernate, recursion, fluent

I have an object that represents a Location. Locations can contain other locations. How can I represent this relationship with Fluent NHibernate. The class looks like this:

```
public class Location : EntityBase
{
    #region Properties
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public Location ParentLocation { get; private set; }

    private List<Location> _locations = new List<Location>();
    public IEnumerable<Location> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
    }

    private List<Device> _devices = new List<Device>();
    public IEnumerable<Device> Devices
    {
        get { return _devices; }
    }

    #endregion
    //Other logic omitted
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's your current mapping? Why doesn't HasManyToMany(map => map.Locations) work?

Comment: @Paco: the property Locations would need a setter to work with Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to get private fields

```
HasManyToMany(Member.Reveal<Location>("_locations"))
```